# Unity3d: Destroy child objects before spawning new game objects on click

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, button

I have a  group of main buttons that instantiates different game objects, when i alternate between these main buttons its clearing all child objects in a display panel and then i call the instantiate function for its according content.

This works, but the result is not ideal, i click one of the main buttons clearing the childs but doesn't spawn the new ones straight away, i have to click it again so then shows its content.

Part 1

```
public void OnClicked(){
    GameObject _manager = GameObject.Find("Manager");
    _manager.gameObject.GetComponent<managerSystem>().clearSubList();
}

public void OnClicked2(){
    GameObject _manager = GameObject.Find("Manager");
    _manager.gameObject.GetComponent<managerSystem>().getSubList(transform.name);
}
```

Part 2

```
public void clearSubList(){
    foreach (Transform child in SubScroll.transform) {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Part 3

```
public void getSubList(string theBName){

    currentSubName = new List<string>();
    currentSubPrice = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.Length; i++ ){
        if (SubScroll.transform.childCount != reader.Length){
            GameObject go = Instantiate(subListButton, SubScroll.transform);
            string [] x = reader[i].Split('/');
            if (x.Length == 2){go.name = x[0]; currentSubName.Add(x[0]); currentSubPrice.Add(x[1]);}
            if (x.Length == 3){go.name = x[0] + " " + x[1]; currentSubName.Add(x[0] + " " + x[1]); currentSubPrice.Add(x[2]);}
            Array.Clear(x, 0, x.Length);
        }
}
```

Is it related to clear the list i call also on the beginning? I have changed to different ways but this works best for me, the two lists on the part 2, they get their content based on the name of a text file and parsing its lines, i removed that part of the code because it would made this more lengthy in case same are wondering where the values are retrieved to this list in the for loop section.

Comment: Which method did you assign to which buttons? Why there are two different methods OnClicked and OnClicked2 for the tasks you want to do at same time?

Comment: Also why `_manager.gameObject`? `_manager` is already a game object and all Components have a GetComponent method, there's never a reason to call `.gameObject` first. Similarly this check is useless: `if (SubScroll.transform.childCount != reader.Length)`, the only way the child count goes up is inside this check and the lip spread is set to run to `reader.length`.

Comment: You know you can do both on the same click ifyou assign onclick to have more than one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Part1: it looks like you have put both methods on the same button click. it may not work since both methods will run on the same time.

As you are trying to clear all the children first and then spawn new objects, therefore, you can achieve this by combining both methods. I merged both onclick methods and modified the code. let me know if it helps.

New Part 1:

```
    public void onClickClearAndSpawnSublist() {

    GameObject _manager = FindObjectOfType(typeof(managerSystem));
    _manager.ClearAndSpawnSublist();
}
```

New Part 3:

```
    public void ClearAndSpawnSublist(string theBName) {

    foreach (Transform child in SubScroll.transform)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }


    currentSubName = new List<string>();
    currentSubPrice = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.Length; i++)
    {
        if (SubScroll.transform.childCount != reader.Length)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(subListButton, SubScroll.transform);
            string[] x = reader[i].Split('/');
            if (x.Length == 2) { go.name = x[0]; currentSubName.Add(x[0]); currentSubPrice.Add(x[1]); }
            if (x.Length == 3) { go.name = x[0] + " " + x[1]; currentSubName.Add(x[0] + " " + x[1]); currentSubPrice.Add(x[2]); }
            Array.Clear(x, 0, x.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unaware that .gameObject could be removed, I separated the part 1 in two methods because I was trying to run the first OnClicked and then the OnClicked2, but yes it could also be together rather than separated. @MuhammadFarhanAqeel the behaviour still remains the same. The MainButton haves the OnClicked method, by clicking it sends its name to another GameObject with the manager component, then it wipes out the lists and removes any object  if any to spawn it again with the new data. Re-doing like you suggested, still, I need to click twice in order to show the info.

Comment: Ok, found the culprit! The reason was the (SubScroll.transform.childCount != reader.Length). By removing this line it clears and spawns straight away. Thank you for the hints and a cleaner code structure.